# post video on facebook using android application

Tags: java, android, facebook, video, camera

This is my code i capture image and share successfully but can't upload video

```
public class CaptureActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ShareButton shareButton;
    private ImageView imgPreview;
    private VideoView videoPreview;
    private Button btnCapture;


    private static final int CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
    private static final int CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE = 200;
    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = 1;
    public static final int MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO = 2;
    private Uri fileUri;
    private static final String IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME = "CityApp";
    static File mediaFile;
    static File mediaStorageDir;
    Bitmap bitmap;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_capture);

        imgPreview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        videoPreview = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoPreview);
        btnCapture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_Capture);

        shareButton = (ShareButton) findViewById(R.id.fb_share_button);
        // shareButton.setFragment(this);
        shareButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                publishImage();
                // publishVideo();
            }
        });

        btnCapture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                selectImage();
            }
        });
    }

    private void selectImage() {
        final CharSequence[] options = {"Take Photo", "Tack Video", "Cancel"};

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(CaptureActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
        builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                if (options[item].equals("Take Photo")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

                    fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);

                    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

                    // start the image capture Intent
                    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
                } else if (options[item].equals("Tack Video")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);

                    fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO);

                    // set video quality
                    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);

                    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri); // set the image file
                    // name

                    // start the video capture Intent
                    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE);

                } else if (options[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }

    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        // save file url in bundle as it will be null on scren orientation
        // changes
        outState.putParcelable("file_uri", fileUri);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        // get the file url
        fileUri = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("file_uri");
    }

    /**
     * Display image from a path to ImageView
     */
    private void previewCapturedImage() {
        try {
            // hide video preview
            videoPreview.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            imgPreview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            // bimatp factory
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();

            // downsizing image as it throws OutOfMemory Exception for larger
            // images
            options.inSampleSize = 8;

            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileUri.getPath(), options);

            imgPreview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
        catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Previewing recorded video
     */
    private void previewVideo() {
        try {
            // hide image preview
            imgPreview.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            videoPreview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            videoPreview.setVideoPath(fileUri.getPath());
            // start playing
            videoPreview.start();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creating file uri to store image/video
     */
    public Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(int type) {
        return Uri.fromFile(getOutputMediaFile(type));
    }

    /**
     * returning image / video
     */
    public static File getOutputMediaFile(int type) {
        // External sdcard location
        mediaStorageDir = new File(
                Environment
                        .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME);

        // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                Log.d(IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME, "Oops! Failed create "
                        + IMAGE_DIRECTORY_NAME + " directory");
                return null;
            }
        }

        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss",
                Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());

        if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE) {
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                    + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");
        } else if (type == MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
            mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                    + "VID_" + timeStamp + ".mp4");
        } else {
            return null;
        }

        return mediaFile;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // successfully captured the image
                // display it in image view
                previewCapturedImage();
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // user cancelled Image capture
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "User cancelled image capture", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            } else {
                // failed to capture image
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! Failed to capture image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        } else if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // video successfully recorded
                // preview the recorded video
                previewVideo();
            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // user cancelled recording
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "User cancelled video recording", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            } else {
                // failed to record video
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Sorry! Failed to record video", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
        }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    public void publishImage() {

        // statusUpdates= new ContactsContract.StatusUpdates(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

        // Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileUri.getPath(), options);


        SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
                .setBitmap(bitmap)
                .setCaption("Testing with android")
                .build();

        SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
                .addPhoto(photo)
                .build();

        shareButton.setShareContent(content);
    }

    public void publishVideo() {

        Uri videoFileUri = fileUri;
        ShareVideo shareVideo = new ShareVideo.Builder()
                .setLocalUrl(videoFileUri)
                .build();
        ShareVideoContent content = new ShareVideoContent.Builder()
                .setVideo(shareVideo)
                .build();
        shareButton.setShareContent(content);
    }
}
```

i want use compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0' this library thanks in advance

Comment: are you having this issue even while trying to upload normal video files? or is it only with screen captured videos?

Comment: problem is my slow internet(2G) now video is upload in facebook successfully @lamdadj22